# miktex-makepk did not succeed because of MEGAFONT

Tags: pdftex, miktex

> Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully
>   contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
>   C:\Users\sndr\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log

In the end of the file this is repeated over and over again

> 2020-02-13 10:32:26,738+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with
>   command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose bbm8 8000
>   8000 magstep(0.0) 2020-02-13 10:32:26,754+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying
>   to make PK font bbm8 at 8000 DPI... 2020-02-13 10:32:26,754+0100 FATAL
>   miktex-makepk - The METAFONT mode could not be determined. 2020-02-13
>   10:32:26,754+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - The METAFONT mode could not be
>   determined. 2020-02-13 10:32:26,754+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
>   2020-02-13 10:32:26,754+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source:  2020-02-13
>   10:32:26,754+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0

The system is `win10 and TeXstudio 2.12.8 and MikTex 2.9 and pdflatex`

What should I do to get the document running?

Comment: 8000 dpi? Is this really with pdflatex? How are you calling pdflatex?

Comment: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex                                                this is what texstudio does by default

Comment: Show a complete small document that can be use for tests.

Comment: i found the solution in one file someone wrote \pdfpkresolution=1000000, which cause the error.